# AudioUnitSampleType in AudioUnit Mixer Host application

Tags: ios, audiounit

I'm going through iOS Audio Units sample application Mixer Host. What confuses me is AudioUnitSampleType seems to hold all the audio data from the files. But AudioUnitSampleType is  a fixed point integer it seems. Is this some sort of array with fixed point integer? otherwise it sorts all sample data in fixed point integer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the samples are normally delivered as signed 16-bit integers. It is possible to request other sample types (such as floating point), but I've never really gotten this to work before. Most apps therefore deal with sint16 and convert it to float on the fly if necessary for the DSP calculations.